# Magento 2. Displaying text on specific days and hours

Tags: magento-2.1, static-block

I got the following piece of code to display specific content on specific days and on specific hours.

I created an static block and pasted the code there, and then called it on a .xml file in Magento, but the code is not showing. I expect that the code works as expected (so specific text showing on specific days and hours).

Does anyone know what I am still missing?

Thanks for your answers.

```
<ul>
<li data-display="hidden" data-day="monday" data-time-start="001" data-time-end="1225">Specific text for Monday</li>
<li data-display="hidden" data-day="tuesday" data-time-start="001" data-time-end="1225">Specific text for Tuesday</li>
<li data-display="hidden" data-day="wednesday" data-time-start="001" data-time-end="1225">Specific text on Wednesday</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can use PHP instead of XML if you want?

Comment: Could you let me know how?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your CMS static block to call phtml file.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::myfiles/myfile.phtml"}}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/myfiles/myfile.phtml

now in **myfile.phtml**, add below code for day and time condition to display specific message.

```
<?php
echo $current_day = date('l');
echo $current_time = date('G:i');

if ($current_day == "Friday") {
    if ($current_time >= '03:45' && $current_time <= '15:45') {
        echo "message";
    }
}
?>
```

You can make modification according to PHP date functions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Hi. I discovered that this option looks great, but it is not the most advisable way in M2, due to caching issues; php can become cached, by which the values would not really change accordingly on time